# compiling a project based on OpenCV in ubuntu

Tags: ros, opencv, rosmake, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have an error when doing cmake [actually rosmake] to my project, I have already installed OpenCV but I have this error:

```
Linking CXX shared library ../lib/libCornerHelper.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_contrib
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_legacy
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_stitching
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_gpu
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_objdetect
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_calib3d
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_features2d
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_video
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_highgui
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_ml
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_imgproc
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_flann
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_core
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../lib/libCornerHelper.so] Error 1
```

How to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12093/compiling-a-project-based-on-opencv-in-ubuntu/) by [Belal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1439/belal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Belal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1439/belal/) on 2011-11-26**:
thanks a lot, it works

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2011-11-25**:
Also the actual command being executed, i.e. export VERBOSE=1

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-11-25**:
The linker cannot find the specified libraries in the linker paths. For more specifics: Your CMake file, manifest.xml, ubuntu and ROS version will help.

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2016-05-15**:
I got the same problem. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you do the following in a shell

```
$ pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv
```

Then accurately check the results of the command.
If there still are missing libraries (as I think it is the case) then run

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate opencv_core (or any other missing lib)
```

This ought to tell you where the libraries are.
Supposedly though nor the linker and neither pkg-config can find them, so probably they ended up installed in a place that is not on the pkg paths.

To check against this eventuality run

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

This variable should contain the path to the OpenCV libs, if it is not so you have to add it OR move the libs in /usr/lib as they ought to be.

To proceed with the second solution you just have to do something like

```
$ sudo cp /root/user/path-to-OpenCV /usr/local/lib
```

For the first solution you have to edit the bash configuration file for your user

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
```

A text editor will open, scroll to the last line. If you already have a line like

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=something
```

than add the path to OpenCV to this line, otherwise create one like so

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=:/path/to/OpenCV
```

Close the shell window, reopen one (ALT+T shortcut) and retry the pkg-config, it should now be able to find your libraries.

---

Originally posted by [Claudio](https://answers.ros.org/users/3152/claudio/) with karma: 859 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1